# Flash CC won't update AIR or Flash Player version

Tags: ios, iphone, flash, air, flash-cc

I am working with Flash CC and since I've downloaded it, new versions of Flash Player and AIR (11.8 and 3.8) have been released.  I have downloaded these updates, but Flash CC won't use the updated versions. In the target bar, the options only go up to 11.6 and 3.6. I have looked around and cant figure out how to update the versions in my projects. How can I update the targets in Flash CC?

Answer (score 0):

Flash.cc menu > help > Manage AIR SDK  then browse to where you unpacked the sdk archive > choose folder,  done!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're installing the AIR runtime. You must download the AIR SDK, not the AIR Runtime. The AIR SDK can be found here:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html

After downloading the appropriate ZIP or TBZ2 file, you can install the SDK from within Flash CC with the option "Help / Manage AIR SDK".

There is no such an option to install updates for newer Flash Player targets, so in that case you have to follow these instructions (it's for CS6 but should work in CC):

http://johnbarrett.net/updating-flash-professional-cs6-to-support-11-5/